# when will margin: auto; work and not work?

Tags: html, css, margin, element

Is this an issue in regards to block and inline elements?

It can be frustrating having to use `margin-left` to center things sometimes.

When `margin:auto` doesn't work, is using margins the only or best alternative?

Please Any one Explain with an Example (or with Jsfiddle)

Comment: In what situation you use `margin: auto;`?

Comment: when you say "using `margin:auto` doesn't work"  do you mean that it is not centering like you would like it to?  because it always works , the reason that it sometimes doesn't center is because of the way the element is positioed

Comment: use `margin: auto` when the parent has full width or just use `text-align: center` on the parent itself

Comment: `text-align: center` is not work..!!   My situation is like this..   [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m4tt79Lz/)

Comment: you are not providing an example of "doesn't work" when you say "When margin:auto doesn't work" We don't know what you perceive as "not working" hence we cannot respond to you.

Comment: you provided a jsfiddle, but you didn't describe what is the current situation, and specifically what is the desired result. we are still in the dark here.

Comment: Do you mean centered horizontal or vertical or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`margin:auto` wont work when you have not set a **width** or when you have a **float**. To center a block element you will have to give it a **width** then only you can use `margin: 0 auto`. This is for **block** elements. For **inline** elements you will have to use `text-align:center`.